# Problem solving Q about number of houses in a street.

Tags: problem-solving

A row is marked with 1,2,3,4....

The marking continues down the other side - the largest mark opposite is 1.

Each mark has another directly opposite it.

If mark 17 is  opposite number 56, how many marks are there in the row?

Comment: Please don't drastically change your question to something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force is an entirely acceptable way to solve this problem. If 17 is opposite 56, then 16 is opposite 57, 15 is opposite 58, and so on. Keep going. Which house is then opposite 1?

Comment: How could I use this to figure out the number of houses in the street?

Comment: @Problemsolving : the number of houses in the street **is** the number of the house opposite house $1$.

Comment: @AndreaMori You're an absolute genius thank you!

Comment: @Problemsolving It doesn't take an absolute genius: "so the largest number is opposite number 1." is clearly spelled out in your problem text.

Answer (score 1):

If the largest number is $N$, what is the sum of the house numbers of house $1$ and the one opposite to it? What is the sum of the house numbers of house $2$ and the one opposite to it?

Comment: Would you mind explaining this response?

Comment: Clever answer that echoes baby Gauss' idea (+1)